# Creating a widget upon clicking a button in flutter using animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm new to flutter I have a search field and upon clicking, it should expand to another input field. I have done it but the widget gets re-created upon clicking the search filed. [image: This is the search field which is to be clicked]

[image]

As you can see, I want these fields to open up nicely with animation so that it looks good. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the second TextField in a AnimatedContainer (or in a SizeTransition, but you will have to use a AnimationController).
If you use a AnimatedContainer you can simply change the height of the widget by a bool and the widget will animate itself. Eg:

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: showSecondField ? 40 : 0,
    child: ...
)
```

or with the SizeTransition:

```dart
class YourWidget extends State<...> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _anim;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
    final CurvedAnimation curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    _anim = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(curve);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: _anim,
      child: TextField()
    );
  }
}
```

And you can open or close with: `_controller.forward()` and `_controller.reverse()`